# which law of probability is used in the following derivation

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

We have two random varibles $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.
The CDF of $\gamma_1$ is
$$
F_{\gamma_1}(\gamma_1)=(1-e^{-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma}})^N
$$
were $\gamma$ is constant.

The PDF of $\gamma_2$ is
$$
f_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_2)=\frac{\gamma_2^{M-1}}{(M-1)!\gamma^M}e^{-\frac{\gamma2}{\gamma}}
$$
We difine a random varible $Z$ as follow
$$Z=\frac{\gamma_1\gamma_2}{\gamma_1+\gamma_2+1}$$

First we want to dirive the CDF of $Z$, so the authors use the following steps

\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=Pr(Z\leq z) \\
&=Pr(\frac{\gamma_1\gamma_2}{\gamma_1+\gamma_2+1}\leq z)
\end{align}
But in the following steps hi use some rules of probability. Can any one explain to me this steps 
\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=Pr(\frac{\gamma_1\gamma_2}{\gamma_1+\gamma_2+1}\leq z)\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}Pr(\gamma_1 \geq\frac{z\gamma_2+z}{\gamma_2-z})f_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_2)d\gamma_2+\int_{z}^{\infty}Pr(\gamma_1 \leq\frac{z\gamma_2+z}{\gamma_2-z})f_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_2)d\gamma_2\\
&=1-\int_{z}^{\infty}Pr(\gamma_1 \geq\frac{z\gamma_2+z}{\gamma_2-z})f_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_2)d\gamma_2
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Hint: how do you rearrange the first inequality into the second.

Comment: i didnt do i found it in PEPER

Comment: $$\frac{\gamma_1\gamma_2}{\gamma_1+\gamma_2+1}\leq z$$     $$\gamma_1\gamma_2\leq z\gamma_1+z\gamma_2+z$$      $$\gamma_1(\gamma_2-z) \leq z\gamma_2+z$$         $$\gamma_1 \leq \frac{z\gamma_2+z }{(\gamma_2-z)}$$

Comment: You divided by $\gamma_2-z$ assuming it was positive; if it's negative, the final inequality will be reversed.

Comment: my question i step 1 2 3 in fig what is law of probability

Comment: for example $A$ and $B$ , $Z=(A^2+B)$ are random variable why $\int_{0}^{z} Pr(a\leq \sqrt(z-b))P_(b)db+\int_{z}^{\infty} Pr(a\geq \sqrt(z-b))P_(b)db$

Comment: That's not a statement; it's a formula. You've missed an equals-something.

Comment: ok suppose we have random varble $Z$ which is function of two random vaible $X$ and $Y$ $Z=f(X,Y)$ , for CDF we have $$F_Z(z)=Pr(z\leq f(X,Y)$$ why we first write  write X as function of Y like in (1)  then we integrate with respect to Y from $0$ to $z$ then from $z$ to $\infty$  like he did in (2). Dose ther is any law of probaility ?